# Checking for DNS resolution errors

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory, powershell-5.1

Problem:
I currently have a script that will add a user to a device's admin group, and I have to use the hostname instead of the IP address.  Occasionally using a hostname does not connect to the correct device (assuming) due to DNS being slow/having issues.

Question:
Is there a way to resolve a hostname using AD and DNS then comparing if they are the same to ensure the correct device is connected to, and failing if they do not match.

The error fixed itself before I was able to finish writing the script, so I am working on theory without a way to test until I have a situation to test this with again.

Based off of the situation I could test - this is what I have so far:

```
$HN = Hostname
$IP = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($HN) | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString
$HNAD = (Get-ADComputer $HN).dnshostname
$HNDNS = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($IPAddress).hostname
```

From there I would have an If statement comparing the two Hostnames to ensure they match, and if they don't - Throw an error.  That's easy, but I am not sure if my theory behind how/where the information is pulled from is correct.

Is this completely off base?  I know there are a few ways to resolve hostnames and IP addresses, but without a testable situation I don't know what path to take.  It seems like it boils down to AD resolving to the wrong device based off of stale DNS information, but I am not 100% sure, I just know being able to compare the two resolutions would help connecting to the wrong device.

Comment: There is actually only one way to resolve hostnames - DNS. AD uses DNS to resolve hostnames. If you have an issue there you should solve it there. To make sure not to run a piece of code on a wrong pc you could query the target machine via a *local command* using PS remoting. ‍♂️

Comment: I know DNS is where the information is coming from, but when I was last running into the issue the Hostname resolving from Get-ADComputer was stale, whereas the one directly querying DNS was the currently active IP address.  Does that make any sense?  I am admittedly self taught so have a lot to learn.

Comment: Hmmm.  When I first responded I didn't register the portion about querying the target machine with a local command.  That's such a simple solution that requires no extra work, thanks for the insight.  I feel foolish even troubleshooting a workaround when a much simpler solution is so obvious haha.  That being said, I am curious as to why I was getting different results depending on using Get-ADComputer or System.Net.DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it best to go with Olaf's recommendation of connecting to the device and then pulling it's COMPUTERNAME variable and comparing to the device you are wanting to connect to.

```
$WorkstationDestinationHN = Invoke-command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $WorkstationHN -ScriptBlock{$env:COMPUTERNAME}
```

Then compare them how you see fit.  In my case I am gathering more data so I don't want it to stop on error, so set it to silently continue.  I had mine in an if then setting triggers for errors after everything is resolved.

```
Try
{
    if ($WorkstationDestinationHN -ne $WorkstationHN)
    {
        $ThrowDestination = 1
        $ThrowError = 1
    }
#Other if statements detecting errors

    if ($ThrowError = 1)
    {
        Throw "Unable to resolve requested information"
    }
}
Catch
{
    if ($ThrowDestination = 1)
    {
        Write-Output "destination device does not match provided information"
    }
}
```

When ThrowError is set to 1 it triggers the catch statement.  The ThrowDestination variable would then be used to know which error messages need to be thrown in the following catch statement.

Comment:  I'm glad you've found a solution what works for you.  I'd try to solve the issues you  seemingly have with your DNS anyway. ‍♂️

Comment: I would if I could.  All I can do is bring it to the attention of those with that scope, but it's been an issue for a while.